# How to filter an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

Can someone help me with filtering an array of objects in javascript? I have an array of `users` such as:

```
var users = [

  {
    first: 'Jon',
    last: 'Snow',
    email: 'jon@got.com'
  },

  {
    first: 'Ned',
    last: 'Stark',
    email: 'ned@got.com'
  },

  {
    first: 'tywin',
    last: 'Lannister',
    email: 'tywin@got.com'
  },

]
```

And I'm trying to write a function to search through the array of objects:

```
function search(str, users) {

  var results = users.filter(function(el) {
    return (el.first === str || el.last === str || el.email === str);
  });

  return results;

}
```

However, doing it this way, my search parameter `str` would have to exactly match the first/last/email value of the user array.. I need the function be able to search based on a substring... Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `String#indexOf`

Comment: Please [search](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+match+substring) before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)  method

```
function search(str, users) {

  var results = users.filter(function(el) {
    return (el.first.indexOf(str)>-1 || el.last.indexOf(str)>-1 || el.email.indexOf(str));
  });

  return results;
}
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :** To make it case insensitive use [`String#toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method (Only supports in latest browsers).

```
function search(str, users) {

  var lStr = str.toLowerCase();
  var results = users.filter(function(el) {
    return (el.first.toLowerCase().indexOf(lStr)>-1 || el.last.toLowerCase().indexOf(lStr)>-1 || el.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(lStr));
  });

  return results;
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2 :** More simplified version using `Array#some` method.

```
function search(str, users) {
  return  users.filter(function(el) {
    return Object.keys(el).some(function(k){
      return el[k].toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toLowerCase())
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Gotcha - is there a way to make it case insensitive also?

Comment: @user1547174 : check updated answer